# libcurl FTP on Linux

Tags: linux, ftp, libcurl

FTP using libcurl:

i am trying to download  file from server...After downloading the file.. checking the file size its showing  34179. but actual file size is different..i tried for many files its giving the same size ..i do not know
whether i have to add some more function..

```
     #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <curl/curl.h>

/* <DESC>
 * Checks a single file's size and mtime from an FTP server.
 * </DESC>
 */ 

static size_t throw_away(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data)
{
  (void)ptr;
  (void)data;
  /* we are not interested in the headers itself,
     so we only return the size we would have saved ... */ 
  return (size_t)(size * nmemb);
}

int main(void)
{
  char ftpurl[] = "ftp://ftp.example.com/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.19.1.tar.bz2";
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  long filetime = -1;
  double filesize = 0.0;
  const char *filename = strrchr(ftpurl, '/') + 1;

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, ftpurl);
    /* No download if the file */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1L);
    /* Ask for filetime */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, 1L);
    /* No header output: TODO 14.1 http-style HEAD output for ftp */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, throw_away);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0L);
    /* Switch on full protocol/debug output */ 
    /* curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); */ 

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(CURLE_OK == res) {
      /* https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html */ 
      res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_FILETIME, &filetime);
      if((CURLE_OK == res) && (filetime >= 0)) {
        time_t file_time = (time_t)filetime;
        printf("filetime %s: %s", filename, ctime(&file_time));
      }
      res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD,
                              &filesize);
      if((CURLE_OK == res) && (filesize>0.0))
        printf("filesize %s: %0.0f bytes\n", filename, filesize);
    }
    else {
      /* we failed */ 
      fprintf(stderr, "curl told us %d\n", res);
    }

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  curl_global_cleanup();

  return 0;
}
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: *"...but actual file size is different..."* - this just says it does not match without providing any details how it does not match. Please specify if you see a pattern, i.e. always too big or always too large, fixed difference or variable. Also check if the reported file size is the wrong one or the actual file size on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you want to download the file, why do you ask libcurl to *not* download the "body", which is the actual file... ?

```
/* No download if the file */ 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1L);
```